# how solve Angular Routing err 400 bad request?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am facing some issue on one route, I am getting 400 error as shown in the screenshot when I try to access the rout, after deleting the cookies its start working fine for few minutes and it will show same error after accessing it 2..3 time.rest of the routs are working fine only the particular route is creating an issue.

please see the module details and component.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { CommonModule, DatePipe } from '@angular/common'
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module'

import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'


import { ModuleRouting } from './manage-profile.module.routing'
import { ManageProfileComponent } from './mange-profile/manage-profile.component'
import { AuthService } from '../shared/service/auth/auth.service'
import { LoginService } from '../login/login.service'
import { AfcService } from '../shared/service/afc-service/afc-service'
import { ManageProfileService } from './manage-profile.service'
import { AreaService } from '../shared/service/locations/area-services/area-service'
import { CommonService } from '../shared/service/common-service/common-service'
import { AuthGuard } from '../shared/service/auth-guard/auth-guard.component'
import { SelectDropDownModule } from '../../../node_modules/ngx-select-dropdown'
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select'
import { ManageConcessionComponent } from './concession-profile/concession-profile.component'
import { ManageLinkAccountsComponent } from './link-accounts/link-accounts.component'
import { ProfileSidebarComponent } from '../core/profile-sidebar/profile-sidebar.component'
import { ChangePasswordModule } from '../change-password/change-password.module'
import { LinkAccountStartPageComponent } from './link-accounts/link-account-start/link-account-start.component'
import { LinkAccountListComponent } from './link-accounts/link-account-list/link-account-list.component'
import { ManageLinkAccountsCreateComponent } from './link-accounts/link-account-create/link-accounts-create.component'
import { TabbingClickDirective } from '../shared/directives/a-tab-clicking.directive'
import { ManageConcessionApplyComponent } from './concession-profile/concession-apply-page/concession-profile-apply.component'
import { ConcessionStartPageComponent } from './concession-profile/concession-start-page/concession-start-page.component'
import { ConcessionCompletePageComponent } from './concession-profile/concession-complete/concession-complete.component'
import { SideBarModule } from '../core/profile-sidebar/SideBar.module'
import { UpdateProfileSubscriptionComponent } from './update-profile-subscription/update-profile-subscription.component'
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    SharedModule,
    ModuleRouting,
    NgbModule,
    SelectDropDownModule,
    NgSelectModule,/* 
    ChangePasswordModule, */
    SideBarModule
  ],
  declarations: [ManageProfileComponent, ManageConcessionComponent, ConcessionStartPageComponent, ConcessionCompletePageComponent, ManageConcessionApplyComponent, ManageLinkAccountsComponent,
    LinkAccountStartPageComponent, LinkAccountListComponent, ManageLinkAccountsCreateComponent,
    TabbingClickDirective, UpdateProfileSubscriptionComponent
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, LoginService, AfcService, AuthGuard, ManageProfileService, DatePipe, AreaService, CommonService]
})
export class ManageProfileModule { }

import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router"
import { ModuleWithProviders } from "@angular/core"
import { ManageProfileComponent } from "./mange-profile/manage-profile.component"
import { AuthGuard } from "../shared/service/auth-guard/auth-guard.component"
import { ManageConcessionComponent } from './concession-profile/concession-profile.component'
import { ManageLinkAccountsComponent } from './link-accounts/link-accounts.component'
import { ManageLinkAccountsCreateComponent } from './link-accounts/link-account-create/link-accounts-create.component'
import { UpdateProfileSubscriptionComponent } from './update-profile-subscription/update-profile-subscription.component'



const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'manage-profile',
        component: ManageProfileComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
    },
    {
        path: 'apply-concession',
        component: ManageConcessionComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
    },
    {
        path: 'linked-accounts',
        component: ManageLinkAccountsComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
    },
    {
        path: 'linked-accounts/link',
        component: ManageLinkAccountsCreateComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
    },
    {
        path: 'manage-subscription',
        component: UpdateProfileSubscriptionComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
    }

]

export const ModuleRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUFSd.png)

Answer (score -1):

Follow official documents use `hashlocationstrategy`, If you don't want to see hash in the URL, you need to change server routing, because your server actually doesn't exist `linked-account` endpoint.

> When the router navigates to a new component view, it updates the browser's location and history with a URL for that view. As this is a strictly local URL the browser won't send this URL to the server and will not reload the page.

> Modern HTML5 browsers support history.pushState, a technique that changes a browser's location and history without triggering a server page request. The router can compose a "natural" URL that is indistinguishable from one that would otherwise require a page load.

https://angular.io/guide/router#locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles